Teams AI Library - JS - Send proactive message
I'm trying to use app.sendProactiveActivity to send a message to the user (1:1 chat), based on the conversationReference I have stored before.
I would like to add a new route to the backend (different from /api/messages) to send the proactive message when this endpoint is called as a webhook from an external system.
When using only app.sendProactiveActivity with the following code:
// Listen for notification requests
server.post("/notify", async (req, res) => {
  // Get the conversationReference for the user
  var conversationReference = await getConversationReference("userId");

  // Send the proactive message
  await app.sendProactiveActivity(conversationReference, "This is the notification");
})

I'm getting the following error message:
{
    "code": "Internal",
    "message": "Error: You must configure the Application with an 'adapter' before calling Application.continueConversationAsync()"
}

When trying to wrap the call in a adapter.process call this way:
// Listen for notification requests
server.post("/notify", async (req, res) => {
  // Get the conversationReference for the user
  var conversationReference = await getConversationReference("userId");

  // Send the proactive message
  await adapter.process(req, res as any, async (context) => {
    await app.sendProactiveActivity(conversationReference, "This is the notification");
  });
})

I'm getting the following error message:
{
    "code": "Internal",
    "message": "Error: validateAndFixActivity(): missing activity type."
}

What should I do?

In Teams AI Library, to send proactive messages with the Application object, it needs to be configured with a TeamsAdapter and the id of the bot to target.
Example:
// Create adapter.
// See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about how bots work.
export const adapter = new TeamsAdapter(
  {},
  new ConfigurationServiceClientCredentialFactory({
    MicrosoftAppId: process.env.BOT_ID,
    MicrosoftAppType: process.env.BOT_TYPE,
    MicrosoftAppTenantId: process.env.BOT_TENANT_ID,
    MicrosoftAppPassword: process.env.BOT_PASSWORD,
  })
);

export const app = new Application<ApplicationTurnState>({
  // Adapter and botAppId are required for the Application to send proactive messages.
  adapter: adapter,
  botAppId: config.MicrosoftAppId,
  storage: storage,
});

Then the notification can be sent with the app.sendProactiveActivity function.
Example:
// Listen for notification requests
server.post("/notify", async (req, res) => {
  // Get the conversationReference for the user
  var conversationReference = await getConversationReference("userId");

  // Send the proactive message
  await app.sendProactiveActivity(conversationReference, "This is the notification");
})


I've covered this topic quite a bit in some other answers, like this one: Sending proactive messages from an outside process to organizational users via Teams chat bot so I'd suggest giving that a read. In short, you don't actually need the the entire conversationReference, just the properties I've outlined in the other answer and code sample. In addition, you don't even need to send the proactive message from the same process or even the same app - you can send it from wherever you like and whenever you like, if you have the right property values. As a result, this should definitely work in a separate webhook.

Thanks Hitlon. These are useful information and reminders.
I am tempted to store only the conversationId and serviceURL objects, but I hesitate because of the documentation and official examples that store the entire conversationReference object.
Anyway, I've found why my code using the Teams AI Library was not working and I have added an answer to the thread.

great, glad to help. I know the docs mostly point to needing, probably because it's easier to get "one" object versus "several" properties, but personally I find it harder to manage. In addition, per your other "closed" question, it -is- possible for the serviceurl to change, in theory, like if the user's account moves from one region to another, so I'd suggest re-saving it if it's changed from one message to another. You want to get it as part of the "welcome" message when the user installs the bot the first time though

While we digress... I have been pointed to a table documenting what should be done with the conversation reference object/properties based on the conversation type (1:1, group, channel) and based on the event.
In case that helps someone: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/interactive-notification-bot-in-teams#notification-based-on-events
I'm now trying to imagine a clever way to check if the conversationReference needs to be added or updated without hitting the database for each message (maybe by caching the database value in the TurnState)

Yes you could definitely do that, just for comparison to see if it's changed. In the end you need it in something more resilient anyway, for the "sending" code to read it. It also depends on where you're storing your turn state in any case - if that's in a database, or anything with a similar or slower I/O, you're back where you started.
